# Change of author not updating

Tags: posts, author

I've created at the bottom of a post a typical author box where I show author's avatar, name and description. It's showing the information correctly but if I change the post author to a different one, it keeps showing the old/original one information.

This is my markup so far:

```
<div class="author-details_info">
    <h2 class="author_info_title"><?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></h2>
    <p class="author_info_desc"><?php the_author_meta('user_description'); ?></p>
    <p class="author_info_mail"><a href="mailto:<?php the_author_meta( 'user_email'); ?>"><?php the_author_meta( 'user_email'); ?></a></p>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if someone could help me fixing that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you caching somehow?

Comment: Yeah I was using WP Fastest Cache – I tried disabling it too but nothing happens.